# Windows 7 Enterprise - How to remove "Maintenance Folder" and its respective shortcuts for all the users in a domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy, maintenance

I am trying to remove the "Maintenance Folder" and cleanup the statr menu for my company. I seem to have hard time to remove this folder. Is there any registry value or GPO setting to deploy in order to remove this folder?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "I seem to have hard time to remove this folder"?  What happens when you just delete it from the start menu? And yes, there's a GPP you can use to delete folders. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I mentioned this is in a domain enviornment and I can't do it for 2000 users manually!? I need to delete this folder, but I couldn't find any GPP to disable/delete this.

Comment: To be clear: the "hard time" your having removing it is not actually removing it, it's that you don't know how to do it for 2000 users?

Comment: Do you know how to do it? Thanks for clarification tho!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Group Policy Preferences' ["Folder" items](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc730913.aspx) to do this.

> Folder preference items allow you to create, update, replace, and *delete* folders and their contents.

Create a new Folder preference item

1. Open the Group Policy Management Console. Right-click the Group Policy object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and then click Edit.
2. In the console tree under Computer Configuration or User Configuration, expand the Preferences folder, and then expand the Windows Settings folder. (you probably want User Configuration for the folder in question).
3. Right-click the Folders node, point to New, and select Folder.
4. In the New Folder Properties dialog box, select an Action for Group Policy to perform. Since you want to delete the folder, set it to **delete**.
5. Enter folder settings for Group Policy to configure or remove. There are several options for the *delete* action. Things like deleting the folder if it also contains files/subfolder (recursive delete), whether it removes read-only files, etc. More information on the options is available in the link, and in the GPP help.
6. Click the Common tab, configure any options, and then type your comments in the Description box.
7. Click OK. The new preference item appears in the details pane.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up hiding the folder instead of deleting it through a GPO setting. I set the folder attribute to hide.